# How can I use Perl to scrape a website that reveals its content with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, windows, perl, internet-explorer, mechanize

I need to write a Perl script to scrape a website. The website can only be scraped with JavaScript, and the user is on Windows.

I got some way with [Win32::IE::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/Win32-IE-Mechanize) on my work machine, which has IE6, but then I moved to my netbook which has IE8, and can't even get as far as fetching a simple page.

Is Win32::IE::Mechanize up to date with the latest versions of IE?

But, more to the point, given a recent WinXP machine, what's the quickest, easiest way to scrape a site which only reveals its content via JavaScript?

Comment: Perhaps Michael Schwern's discussion of Selenium in a testing situation will be of interest to you: http://use.perl.org/~schwern/journal/39088.

Answer (score 4):

[WWW::Selenium](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3A%3ASelenium).

- It allows you to specify which browser to use (IE and Firefox are supported from the get-go)
- It supports access to elements via xpath elements, table IDs, text (regex-matching!) and URLs
- It provides a Swiss army knife of user-interaction options, giving you flexibility over how you wish to simulate end-user browsing

You'll need to download the [Selenium Remote Control](http://selenium-rc.seleniumhq.org/) and have it running in the background for the module to work.

It may not be a good option if your page load times are unpredictable.

Comment: That certainly looks good but the installation of the RC part isn't going to be any fun for my geographically remote, somewhat clueless clients...

Comment: @AmbroseChapel: It's not so much an installation as it is a download. Once the file is in place, run it via `java -jar selenium-server.jar` in the background.

Comment: Or, these days, [Selenium::Chrome](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Chrome) (or `::Firefox`), with no need for a standalone server or JRE. (It may fall back to [Selenium::Remote::Driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver)).  Much nicer to use, no caveats.

Comment: Twelve years on one would hope so :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Win32::Watir](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::Watir). It's a newer module and explicitly supports IE 6, 7 and 8.

Comment: It looks great. But I can't even get it to run. It fails on new() and gives me an error message. "Odd number of elements in hash assignment at C:\Perl\site\lib\Win32\Watir.pm line 101 Can't locate object method "_startIE" via package "visble" at C:\Perl\site\lib\Win32\Watir.pm line 108" Any advice?

Comment: Oh wait, it's the documentation -- it says Watir::new when it should say Watir->new -- it's working now. Though that didn't fill me with confidence...

Comment: I didn't but I submitted a bug. I should go back and do the documentation thing, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any mention of [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Mechanize), so I'll bring it up just for completeness.  [Selenium](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Selenium) is also becoming very popular and can be used in a lot of testing scenarios.

Comment: WWW::Mechanize doesn't do JavaScript, that's really why I'm here asking this question.

Comment: @AmbroseChapel: `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` does support JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

[WWW::Scripter](http://search.cpan.org/~sprout/WWW-Scripter-0.011/lib/WWW/Scripter.pod) and its ::Plugin::Javascript can probably help you.