# Selenium Testing

Tags: perl, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide, gui-testing

I want to get a bunch of dom-objects with xpath and loop through those to check if they contains a specified text, is this possible in the Selenium IDE or rc?
Perl is my prefered language

XPath would be something like
xpath=//tbody[@class='table-data']/tr/td/div[@class='table-item']

This would return all row items in the table, but i need to check each div if contains a specified text string. Is this possible with Selenium?

Best regards

Comment: WWW::Selenium is the obvious part (or Test::WWW::Selenium).  Could someone answer more explicitly the "test that multiple divs matching an xpath all contain specified text"?  Or at least show a hint of how to do the "multiple" or "contain specified text" parts?

Answer (score 1):

The [`WWW::Selenium`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3A%3ASelenium) module is perfect for your need.

From an [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703902/how-can-i-use-perl-to-scrape-a-website-that-reveals-its-content-with-javascript/2705285#2705285) to another question:

> It supports access to elements via xpath elements, table IDs, text (regex-matching!) and URLs...
>
> You'll need to download the [Selenium
> Remote
> Control](http://selenium-rc.seleniumhq.org/)
> and have it running in the background
> for the module to work.
>
> A caveat is that it may not be a good option if your page load times are unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is XPath searching of HTML there's [a number of modules to choose from](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=xpath&mode=all), but [Test::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test::XPath) looks the best of the lot.

```
  use Test::XPath;

  my $html = ...get it however...

  # Create a Test::XPath object from your HTML
  my $tx = Test::XPath->new( xml => $html, is_html => 1 );

  # Test for the existence of your table rows.
  $tx->ok( q{//tbody[@class='table-data']/tr/td/div[@class='table-item']}, sub {
      # Run more tests on each node returned by the above xpath expression
      $_->like( './text()', qr/specified text/, "row contains the right text" );
  }, 'found table rows' );
```

My XPath may be a little off, but you get the idea.