# Configuring Selenium RC with Perl

Tags: perl, selenium-rc

I want to use Selenium RC with a Perl client driver. How can I configure Selenium RC with Perl?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`WWW::Selenium`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3A%3ASelenium) module to link up to Selenium RC.

You will need to have Selenium RC running in the background in order for it to operate.
A technique that I have found useful to launch it from within Perl is to execute it on a separate thread and then immediately `detach` it:

```
use threads;

my $seleniumThread = # Assumes that your Selenium RC file is in the current dir
   threads->create( sub { system "java -jar selenium-server.jar"; } );

$seleniumThread->detach;
# Avoids the main program from having to wait for the system call to end
```

---

The following question may be useful as well:

> - [How can I use Perl to scrape a website that reveals its content with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703902/how-can-i-use-perl-to-scrape-a-website-that-reveals-its-content-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Just a heads-up... for Selenium 2.0, you'll want to use the `Selenium::Remote::Driver` module instead; `WWW:Selenium` is for 1.0.

From the Selenium docs (http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html):

> Perl bindings are provided by a third party, please refer to any of their documentation on how to install / get started. There is one known Perl binding as of this writing. [with a link to [https://metacpan.org/module/Selenium::Remote::Driver](http://metacpan.org/module/Selenium%3a%3aRemote%3a%3aDriver)]